# Invalid keystore format error while implementing SSO with SAML in EAP wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, single-sign-on, wildfly-8, picketlink

This is the first time I have tried to implement SSO with SAML
I am configuring the machine for the SP and have done all configurations for the same.

In my standalone.xml I have imported the key i generated using ketool

```
C:\Users\bpledam\EAP-7.0.0\standalone\configuration>keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias bpledamselfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -validity 365 -keysize 2048
```

However when JBOSS starts I receive the following error

> 10:30:41,334 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "bpledam.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./bpledam" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./bpledam: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.picketlink.common.exceptions.TrustKeyProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.picketlink.common.exceptions.TrustKeyProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.picketlink.common.exceptions.TrustKeyProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
>       Caused by: org.picketlink.common.exceptions.TrustKeyProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format"}}

My Standalone.xml code to import jks is as follows.

```
        <security-realm name="UndertowRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl protocol="TLS">
                    <keystore path="keystore.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="changeit" alias="bpledamselfsigned" key-password="changeit"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
        </security-realm>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried your solution on Wildfly (non-EAP) and it worked for me. Check that keystore is valid by listing its contents using command `keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks`.

Comment: I tried that it lists everything perfectly!!

Comment: Then please post the whole configuration file.

Comment: Sure I will do that later as I do not have access to it now!! But thanks for taking out the time to help me out with this ...appreciate it!!